# Python declaring variable vs not declaring

Tags: python, sum

I have two different code blocks

I'm trying to sum all of the variables in a dataset.

The second code block works, while the first gives me the 'wrong' answer. I'm guessing this is due to the fact that I used the variable 'total' before giving it a value.

I was wondering, what kind of computation does python make in this situation? What is the 'total' being assigned as?

Thanks,

Code #1

```
 for num in df['Data']:
        total = total + num
```

Code #2

```
total = 0
for num in df['Data']:
            total = total + num
```

Comment: Code #1 will give you an error because total is not declared.

Comment: Python doesn't make any kind of "computation" in this situation. If `total` already has a value, that is the value that will be used.

Comment: As hallaksec says, Code #1 will not work... unless your Code #1 is actually *after* Code #2, in which case it will use the (already updated) value of ```total``` from Code #2. To avoid this you would have to reset ```total``` back to 0 as you did in Code #2.

Comment: What is this 'wrong' answer that it gives you? Surely it breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 1st section of code you have written:

```
total = total + num
```

If `total` doesn't exist how can it add `total` to `num`?

Also perhaps a cleaner way of doing this is using `+=`:

```
total = 0
for num in df['Data']:
    total += num
```

Comment: It may be cleaner to write df['Data'].sum() ?